# Implement a web server in Windows Phone 8

Tags: sockets, windows-phone-8, webserver, windows-phone

I want to implement a web server in my windows phone 8 app that users can download files from my phone app or upload form a PC using desktop browser.

please help me how can i do this ???

Comment: -1 - this is too broad a question. Take some time to research and come back if you have more specific questions.

Comment: How many times are you going to ask the same question?

Comment: Atul : yes i want to use my phone app as web server.

Comment: I am not sure about windows phone but if you have android you can do it.. check out following http://lifehacker.com/5920173/use-your-android-phone-as-a-full-fledged-web-server

Comment: By the way why do you want to do that? What data you want to serve from your phone?

Comment: Images , doc, videos ....

Comment: also i want to transfer file form PC to Phone.....

Comment: This topic is also interesting regarding uPnP/DLNA functionality. Since there is no other way to publish an Image/Video/Music file to a DLNA renderer device.

Comment: I dont know why somebody downvote this question, i dont think this question can be more specific than it already is. so plus one from my side

Answer (score 1):

I have tried it on emulator only by myself and i hope you are going to like it. this project is still in alpha stage.

it is inspired by xda developers project but provides basic web service functionality which I believe can be used on marketplace apps as well.

http://wp8webserver.codeplex.com/

download its source code and remove registry and file system features from sample and you are good to go.

I am currently try to make a working sample, i would try to share them really soon.

Answer (score 1):

I made myself a small webserver stub with an example project. Only simple GET and file download operations, yet maybe useful for a start:
[IDCT WebServer WP8 on GitHub](https://github.com/ideaconnect/wp8-simple-web-server)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this proyect: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2355034

This is the continuation of the NODO webserver and WebServer for Mango, but you should fully unlock your phone to make it work.

Answer (score -2):

Sorry but this is not possible.  The relevant libraries are not available for a start and also the Phone Framework does not allow the phone to be used as an endpoint.

The most you can do is open a socket from within an application as it's running for networking.

Comment: Actually, since you can listen to socket connections, it could be used as an endpoint.

Comment: Yes you can listen to sockets but A:) you app must be running B:) you need a registered protocol which cannot be one of the standard ones C:) the HTTP service is just a subset for doing outward requests, not inbound

Comment: Possible on Windows Phone 8:
https://github.com/ideaconnect/wp8-simple-web-server